# How to display an object you created on a JtextArea

Tags: java

i am having a gui issue. my gui is a bank. i am able to create an account object and store its data into a text file. 
my gui can also read the file but it will only display if i manually enter the data into the text file.
from creating an object on the gui, i can not display it straight away without closing and re opening the gui.
 is there a way to search and display what i created on my gui at the same time?

```
Account account;


            if (values[3].equalsIgnoreCase("Savings"))
            {
                account = new SavingsAccount(values[1], Double.parseDouble(values[2]));
                account.setAccountNo(Integer.parseInt(values[0]));
           account.setaccountType("Savings");
            }
```

after creating this account object , i realize that this is reading off the text. but if i were to create an object then try display at the same time it wont until i reopen the gui.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more code? For example the code part where you are reading your textFile (and where you are trying to display it)...And what does the code snippet you provided has to do with your problem?